# Servlet load picture/jpg won't work

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I have xampp installed. With it, I got the tomcat required for java servlets to work. `C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\SavedFiles`. This is the path for tomcat, considering it is installed with the xampp.

I have the following :
`D:\School\Uni\S1\WEB\UploadFileToServer\out\artifacts\UploadFileToServer_war_exploded` this is the output directory for my artifacts (I use intellij, if this matters).
`SavedFiles` contains: `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `picture.bmp`.

I know that I need to add a context and a path or something like that, so that I can display images stored on my computer but I am lost here.
I have images in `SavedFiles`.

What do I need to add to the servlet or tomcat `server.xml` so that I can display the images like this `<img src='SavedFiles/1.jpg'>`?

Comment: @BalusC, I know I had a different question, but this one is the sum up of what I have, what I was able to do and what I am unable to do or I do not understand. Please be patient with me, I do my best to understand.

Comment: Is this a continuation of your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854319/get-saved-files-name-using-jsp-servlet-and-display-selected-file    ?

Comment: @rickz, Actually, I want to delete that question. I think it is confusing. This is the real question I actually have.

Comment: Are you trying to use <img> tag to access image from a HTML file? If yes, then where is that HTML file located? Is it within another web app?

Comment: I use the `<img>` tag inside my `index.jsp` file.

Comment: This `getServletContext().getContextPath()` returns me void string.

Comment: Ok, but where is that index.jsp file located?

Comment: The index.jsp is inside my app, in D:\School\...

Comment: @rickz, how about the `path` you were talking? I get the contextPath() as being void string. Same for `request.getContextPath()`

Comment: The contextPath of the ROOT web app is an empty String.  Is that the web app you are using?

Comment: What? I said that I use an app that is deployed on the following path `D:\School\Uni\S1\WEB\UploadFileToServer\out\artifacts\UploadFileToServer_war_exploded` but the context path seems to be an empty string and this seems as a problem to me, but I couldn't fix it...

Comment: I am sorry that I couldn't help you. I have not used XAMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was that I used the `path` instead of `getRealPath("/")`. This solved the problem for me. Maybe this will help someone in future as well.